# Tibco BusinessWorks - Projlibs and GVs

Tags: tibco, businessworks

I have a BW project importing multiple prjlib files. I want to test the project locally, but all the imported projlib global variables are greyed out. I know I can create the vars locally on the disk, but that is a very messy solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a properties file that you want to overwrite all your Global variables and reference the file when you about to perform the local testing.
In order to overwrite the global varible you will need the following prefix "tibco.clientVar." follow by the structure of the folder and variable. See example below

i.e. local.properties under C drive

```
tibco.clientVar.TestProject/Connection/JMS/Username=user1
tibco.clientVar.TestProject/Connection/DB/Timeout=60
```

etc.....

Always leave an empty line after your last global variable. If not your properties won't work correctly.

So when you run the tester in Desginer, after clicked the play button, select Advanced. under the Test Engine User Args column enter the following `-p C:\local.properties`
then click ok. 
This will overwrite the global variable you set in your properties file. Any Global variable that is not in the file will use the default value in the project.

Comment: Excellent, that is exactly what I was looking for. Apologies for late reply

Answer (score 0):

What samw2k00 suggested is one of the ways to do it.

This is not a best practice, but, if you want to have access to the projlib processes and GVs, you can go to File --> Save As, and save the project locally. With this you can get access to the GVs and the process definitions, and can play around with them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create one properties file for GV's whose reference you have to give in one file named same as your project name is created for your project, whenever you run first time any process in your project.

Path will be : c:/users/[username/system name]/.Tibco/BW Debug/[File for your project].

You have to open above file and enter below line :

usrargs= -p [Property file full path]

Suppose Your property file is saved at D:/property/ProjectName.prop

usrargs = -p D/://property//ProjectName.prop

Now , In property file you have to mention all GV value you want to change in runtime like this :

tibco.clientVar.TestProject/Connection/JMS/Username=user1
tibco.clientVar.TestProject/Connection/DB/Timeout=60

So, Mention how many variables you want to change in runtime into this property file.